# The members in the source code of NetBeans JForm takes forever to load

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans

I am using NetBeans IDE 8.0.1 for a GUI Application. Whenever I increase the amount of code in the source for Actions performed, after a certain amount of code, the members in the Navigation tile vanish and displays "Please Wait...". What could be the problem and how to overcome it ? There is no problem in the code as it is very simple.

Comment: The JVM running Netbeans may have been assigned too little memory.  Look into if the garbage collector runs very frequently.

Comment: How to do it? I searched online but the search result says to look into project profile which i cannot do as my application has no main class. Please help !

Comment: Not for your application.  For netbeans itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having the same problem a few months ago. I changed the frequency of garbage collector and the members loaded without any problem. This, I see is exactly what Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen has said.